# Converting scrambled alphabet

Tags: python

I need to take an input of a scrambled alphabet and covert it to the A-Z alphabet.

I think I need to change these to integers.

Any idea how to take a scrambled input and changed it to integers?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code I've written so far. I can't use the built in functions posted, must be things we've learned already.

If the user input is:

```
VNKW KW BO 1WV WJHFJV BJWWXEJ!
```

the desired output is:

```
THIS IS MY 1ST SECRET MESSAGE
```

---

```
import random

def main():
    encrypt = [" "] * 26   #all letters available

    for numbah in range(26):
        letter = chr(numbah+65)
        print (letter, end="")
        # find position for number
        notfound = True
        while notfound:
            position = random.randint(0, 25)
            if encrypt[position] == " ":
                notfound = False
        encrypt[position] = letter

    print("\nScrambled: ", end="")
    for numbah in range(26):
        print(encrypt[numbah], end="")
    print("\n\n ")

    msg=input("Please input the scrambled alphabet in order: ")

    print("Now input the scrambled message:  " + msg)
    print("Your unscrambled message reads: ", end="")
    for alpha in msg.upper():
        if alpha < "A" or alpha > "Z":
            print(alpha,end="")
        else:
            print(encrypt[ ord(alpha) - 65 ], end="")

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow! In general, the more you give us, the more we can give back to you. Please give us some more details - how is the alphabet represented (as a string, a list, etc...)? What have you tried so far? As a side note, you don't need to ask for help or say "thanks", that's what the upvotes and accept button are for!

Comment: Discouraging saying "thanks" is absurd.

Comment: lol at `numbah` variable name

Comment: I tried to enter in possible_position = chr (88 81 72 65 74 68 69 78 75 76 84 67 66 90 71 85 89 70 87 86 77 73 80 83 79 82) but it wont let me enter that many numbers. How do I substitue each character without writing 26 if statements?

Comment: @Julian It's just consensus: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/168269

Comment: Are we supposed to _guess_ what you have _learned already_ too?

Answer (score 8):

Since this is a homework question, I only hint you at the functions you could use to easily implement this: Take a look at [`string.maketrans()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Comment: "Since this is a homework question, I only hint..." +1 lol (and agreed).

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the ASCII number of a specific character, you can use [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord).

`print ord("a") => 97`

You can then manipulate this value, and convert back to an ASCII character using [`chr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr).

`print chr(98) => "b"`

This should give you a good head start. You can view all the ASCII character numbers [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: I tried to enter in                possible_position = chr (88 81 72 65 74 68 69 78 75 76 84 67 66 90 71 85 89 70 87 86 77 73 80 83 79 82)     but it wont let me enter that many numbers. How do I substitue each character?

Comment: @ChrisB. You can only do it on one character at a time. Look at using a `for` loop to avoid repetition. To help answer better, what are the numbers you showed representing?

Comment: The numbers represent XQHAJDENKLTCBZGUYFWVMIPSOR for the alphabet

Comment: That is done for you within the string class. You could do `for c in string.ascii_uppercase:` to get access to each character. To solve this problem though, you first need to work out how your text is encrypted, so that you can do the opposite to get it back to its decrypted form. Have you worked that out yet?